# Get UTC time in seconds

Tags: bash, date, datetime

It looks like I can't manage to get the bash UTC date in second. I'm in Sydney so + 10hours UTC time

```
 date
 Thu Jul 3 17:28:19 WST 2014

 date -u
 Thu Jul 3 07:28:20 UTC 2014
```

But when I tried to convert it, I'm getting the same result which is not UTC time

```
 date +%s
 1404372514

 date -u +%s
 1404372515
```

What am I missing here?

---

After getting an answer saying `date +%s` was returning UTC time, here are more details about the problem I'm facing now.

I'm trying to compare a date written in a file with python. This date is written in seconds in UTC time. And the bash `date +%s` doesn't give me the same one. Actually if I'm doing in python `time.asctime(time.localtime(date_in_seconds_from_bash))`, I get the current time of Sydney, not UTC. I don't understand.

Comment: Return value of `date +%s` is indeed UTC

Answer (score 42):

I believe `+%s` is seconds since epoch. It's timezone invariant.

Comment: anyway to get date in UTC seconds then?

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale According to `date --help`: `%s   seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Adding `-u` doesn't give a difference. It would still print based from UTC. This is the reason why you were getting the same values.

Comment: Both your answers above are correct. UTC Seconds is the same anywhere in the world, and so is useful for unambigious timestamps. Seconds since 1970 midnight in Sydney could be calculated by taking the difference between that time and UTC zero time (-neg 11 or so hours I suppose), but that number is probably not what you want.

Comment: My problem is i'm trying to compare a date written in a file with python.This date is written in seconds in UTC time. And the bash 'date +%s doesn't give me the same one. Actually if i'm doing in python time.asctime(time.localtime(date_in_seconds_from_bash)), I get the current time of sydney not UTC. I don't understand

Answer (score 27):

I bet this is what was intended as a result.

```
$ date -u --date=@1404372514
Thu Jul  3 07:28:34 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 14):

You say you're using:

```
time.asctime(time.localtime(date_in_seconds_from_bash))
```

where `date_in_seconds_from_bash` is presumably the output of `date +%s`.

The `time.localtime` function, as the name implies, gives you *local time*.

If you want UTC, use `time.gmtime()` rather than `time.localtime()`.

As [JamesNoonan33's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547736/827263) says, the output of `date +%s` is timezone invariant, so `date +%s` is exactly equivalent to `date -u +%s`. It prints the number of seconds since the "epoch", which is `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The output you show in your question is entirely consistent with that:

```
date -u
Thu Jul 3 07:28:20 UTC 2014

date +%s
1404372514   # 14 seconds after "date -u" command

date -u +%s
1404372515   # 15 seconds after "date -u" command
```

Answer (score 6):

One might consider adding this line to `~/.bash_profile` (or [similar](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)) in order to can quickly get the current UTC both as current time and as seconds since the epoch.

`alias utc='date -u && date -u +%s'`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from the other @Adam, here is a one-liner with the UTC date-time and seconds since epoch start:

```bash
alias utc='printf "%s : %s\n" "$(date -u)" "$(date -u +%s)"'
```

The epoch start time is defined as the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 at 00:00 Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), a timezone now known as UTC±00:00 or simply UTC.

Answer (score 0):

> time.asctime(time.localtime(date_in_seconds_from_bash)), I get the
> current time of Sydney, not UTC. I don't understand.

You're kind of answering your own question here, but missing the important bits from the documentation. You got a good UTC time from the shell with date command. Then you're passing it to python's time.localtime() ... which explicitly accepts a UTC timestamp in seconds and returns a Python time value that's localized to the timezone, or at least whatever Python thinks is the timezone:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime

If you want it to remain in UTC, then probably what you are after is time.gmtime() instead of time.localtime():

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.gmtime